# RegEx validation in M1 (Magento 1.9.4) for eav attribute_code in extension does not work

Tags: regex

I have an extension where customer attributes are created (magento 1.9.4).
except for the validation of the passed variable, the extension works fine.
in the controller there is a regex-test.
Unfortunately, i have no idea about regular expressions.
here is the problem (saveAction):

```
    public function saveAction() {

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($data) {
        /** @var $session Mage_Admin_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');

        $redirectBack = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
        /* @var $model Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Attribute */
        $model = Mage::getModel('customerattribute/customerattribute');
        /* @var $helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product */
        $helper = Mage::helper('customerattribute');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');

        //validate attribute_code
        if (isset($data['attribute_code'])) {
            // Dudit 2019 Validierung hat Fehler
            if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>=')) {
                $validatorAttrCode = new Zend_Validate_Regex(array('pattern' => '/^[a-z_]{1,255}$/'));
                if (!$validatorAttrCode->isValid($data['attribute_code'])) {
                    $session->addError(
                            $helper->__('Attribute code is invalid. Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (!preg_match('/^[a-z_]{1,255}$/', $data['attribute_code'])) {
                    $session->addError(
                            $helper->__('Attribute code is invalid. Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        //validate frontend_input
        if (isset($data['frontend_input'])) {
            if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.5.1', '>=')) {
                /** @var $validatorInputType Mage_Eav_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Inputtype_Validator */
                $validatorInputType = Mage::getModel('eav/adminhtml_system_config_source_inputtype_validator');
                if (!$validatorInputType->isValid($data['frontend_input'])) {
                    foreach ($validatorInputType->getMessages() as $message) {
                        $session->addError($message);
                    }
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (!in_array($data['frontend_input'], array('text', 'textarea', 'date', 'boolean', 'multiselect', 'select'))) {
                    $session->addError('Error1');
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);

            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $session->addError(
                        Mage::helper('customerattribute')->__('This Attribute no longer exists'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

            // entity type check
            if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                $session->addError(
                        Mage::helper('customerattribute')->__('This attribute cannot be updated.'));
                $session->setAttributeData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

            $data['attribute_code'] = $model->getAttributeCode();
            $data['is_user_defined'] = $model->getIsUserDefined();
            $data['frontend_input'] = $model->getFrontendInput();
        } else {
            /**
             * @todo add to helper and specify all relations for properties
             */
            $data['source_model'] = $helper->getAttributeSourceModelByInputType($data['frontend_input']);
            $data['backend_model'] = $helper->getAttributeBackendModelByInputType($data['frontend_input']);
        }

        if (!isset($data['is_configurable'])) {
            $data['is_configurable'] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($data['is_filterable'])) {
            $data['is_filterable'] = 0;
        }
        if (!isset($data['is_filterable_in_search'])) {
            $data['is_filterable_in_search'] = 0;
        }

        if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
            $data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($data['frontend_input']);
        }

        $defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($data['frontend_input']);
        if ($defaultValueField) {
            $data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
        }

        if (!isset($data['apply_to'])) {
            $data['apply_to'] = array();
        }

        //filter
        $data = $this->_filterPostData($data);

        $model->addData($data);

        if (!$id) {
            $model->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId);
            $model->setIsUserDefined(1);
        }


        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('set') && $this->getRequest()->getParam('group')) {
            // For creating product attribute on product page we need specify attribute set and group
            $model->setAttributeSetId($this->getRequest()->getParam('set'));
            $model->setAttributeGroupId($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'));
        }

        try {
            $model->save();
            $used_in_forms = $this->getRequest()->getParam('used_in_forms');
            if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>=')) {
                if ($model->getId() && is_array($used_in_forms)) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
                            ->getAttribute('customer', $model->getAttributeCode())
                            ->setData('used_in_forms', $used_in_forms)
                            ->save();
                }
            } else {
                if ($model->getId()) {
                    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                    $condition = $connection->quoteInto('attribute_code = ?', $data['attribute_code']);
                    $table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('officustomerattribute');
                    $connection->delete($table, $condition);
                    foreach ($used_in_forms as $valueattr) {
                        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
                        $fields = array('form_code' => $valueattr, 'attribute_code' => $data['attribute_code']);
                        $connection->insert($table, $fields);
                        $connection->commit();
                    }
                }
            }
            $session->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('customerattribute')->__('The product attribute has been saved.'));

            /**
             * Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation
             */
            Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
            $session->setAttributeData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('popup')) {
                $this->_redirect('adminhtml/catalog_product/addAttribute', array(
                    'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('product'),
                    'attribute' => $model->getId(),
                    '_current' => true
                ));
            } elseif ($redirectBack) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/', array());
            }
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->addError($e->getMessage());
            $session->setAttributeData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

if I comment out the following code, then everything works:

```
            //validate attribute_code
        if (isset($data['attribute_code'])) {
            // Dudit 2019 Validierung hat Fehler
            if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>=')) {
                $validatorAttrCode = new Zend_Validate_Regex(array('pattern' => '/^[a-z_]{1,255}$/'));
                if (!$validatorAttrCode->isValid($data['attribute_code'])) {
                    $session->addError(
                            $helper->__('Attribute code is invalid. Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (!preg_match('/^[a-z_]{1,255}$/', $data['attribute_code'])) {
                    $session->addError(
                            $helper->__('Attribute code is invalid. Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

that's why i think there is a mistake in the regular expressions.
an example of 'attribute_code':

```
s24_testfield
```

this string is valid, but still generates the error message in the regular expression

can someone help me? what's wrong here?
Of course, I can do without the validation, but that would be a dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer it myself.
I do not understand the reason yet, but there is still a flag to set:

```
/^[a-z\_0-9]{1,255}$/m
```

I do not really understand the "why", but it works. The input can actually only be single-line and not multiline, but it must be due to my delimiters "^" and "$".